# how to handle Notification when app State is UIApplicationStateInactive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using following code to handle push notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{               
     if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) 
     {
          //************************************************************
          // I only want this called when user click on notification.
          //************************************************************

          NSLog(@"Inactive");
          if ([[userInfo valueForKey:@"noty_type"] isEqualToString:@"web"])
          {
                if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo valueForKey:@"url"]]])
                {
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo valueForKey:@"url"]]];
                                    });
                }
          }
     }

     if((application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
     {
          // I am useing local notification when app in Forground
          UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
          localNotification.soundName =  @"Default";
          localNotification.alertBody = [userInfo valueForKey:@"msg"];
          localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: localNotification];
     }
}
```

This code open the url in safari browser. this code work fine When my app in background and notification come and I click on notification check the applicationState and open the url with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL`.

now the scenario that generate the problem.

1. I open my app .
2. and Down the notification UI

[image]

3. now Send the notification from server
4. `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`  method get called.
5. Now I get the `ApplicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive` .

"It open into the safari browser without any user interaction".

```
I only want this called when user click on notification.
```

So, How can I handle this condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
{
    // do something when app open with notification
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know why the app is inactive.  The two possibilities are that the app was in the background and the user is bringing it to the foreground (by tapping on the notification banner), or something like the notification center was pulled down or the user got a system alert.

To tell the difference, keep track of when the user enters the background.  Just set a boolean in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` delegate method, and clear it when the app is resigning active.

```
static BOOL didEnterBackground;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Launching the app is kind of like coming from background.
    didEnterEnterBackground = YES;

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    didEnterBackground = NO;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    didEnterBackground = YES;
}
```

Now you can check the variable `didEnterBackground` to determine how the app got to the inactive state when you're handling a notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        if (didEnterBackground) {
            // The user tapped the notification
        }
        else {
            // The app was inactive, but not in the background.
            // Ignore notification, or do whatever the app does
            // when receiving a notification while active.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am use local notification if app in forground. the problem is UIApplicationStateInactive . if i use boolen how to manage it.

Comment: You only want tapping the notification to launch Safari if the user tapped the banner, correct?

Comment: yes   to launch Safari if the user tapped the banner.

Comment: applicationDidEnterBackground: not get called when i down the notificatin ui only  applicationWillResignActive get Called.

Comment: I done the same thing @Avi . but Tester say i have to show notification. it i show local notification in your  else part . i come into same problem in didReceiveLocalNotification methode.

Comment: My example is handling a local notification.

Comment: i can not  Ignore notification avi. and if i show the local notification and notification window is down . your didEnterBackground bool still no so then case what i do.

Comment: I gave example code that shows how to figure out what state you're in.  If you can't adapt it to do whatever your app needs, you need to be a lot more specific as to what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
 fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
 }//iOS below 9

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier 
  forLocalNotification:(nonnull UILocalNotification *)notification 
  completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)())completionHandler {


// handling local and interactive notifcation 

 } // iOS 9 and above
```

Which is used to trigger the notification in background state.